# Remove half opaque pixels when rendering final image

Tags: rendering, export, pixel-art

Im doing some work to test styles with a model i came up with. In those styles i wanted to test how it would look like if it were to mimic a prerendered snes sprite, like from the Donkey Kong Country series or Super Mario RPG. The only problem is these pixels that are part of the sprite but have some alpha in it. These half opaque pixels break the whole pipeline i have to treat the sprites and make them look better for the style. Heres how i get them from rendering in blender and after some color reduction and other treatments:

[image] [image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak the *Film > Filter Size* option to `0.00px` in the Output side bar menu:

[image]